# How to compare XML enum with Java enum?

Tags: java, enums

Does anybody know how to compare the below two enums?

```
test.XMLResponseType.SUCCESS
@XmlEnumValue(value="Success")

public enum JavaResponseType{
SUCCESS,FAIL
}
```

i have one Response from web-service, which Returns Success/Fail tag like

```
public static final enum test.ResponseType SUCCESS;
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue(value="Success")

public static final enum test.ResponseType FAIL;
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue(value="Fail")
```

and i have implemented Success/Fail constant in my java code like

```
public enum JavaResponseType{
SUCCESS,FAIL
}
```

now i want to compare success/fail between two types as i mentioned here.
is there any way to compare with each other or i should change my implementation ?

Comment: ResponseType.name().equals(JavaResponseType.SUCCESS.name()) and ResponseType.name().equalsIgnoreCase(JavaResponseType.SUCCESS.name()) both are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (enum1.name().equalsIgnoreCase(enum2.name())) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

or

```
if (JavaResponseType.SUCCES.name().equalsIgnoreCase(enum1.name())) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, this would always return false, since the objects are from different classes.

Comment: your correct, didn't saw the 2 different classes. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string value to compaire like enum1.name().equals(enum2.name())

Answer (score 0):

Adding a method to compare with specific enum, as following

```
public enum JavaResponseType {
    SUCCESS, FAIL;

    boolean compareWithEnum2(test.XMLResponseType value) {
                  return name().equalsIgnoreCase(value.name());
    }

}
```